# Mutation Obervers in Chrome are not detecting attribute and css changes

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome, mutation-observers

I am in Chrome 19 and I created a new mutation observer object:

```
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
  console.log(mutations, observer);
});
```

And then I observe:

```
observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  attribute: true      
});
```

It seems that this setup only gets triggered when i insert or remove a node, or change the text of a node. It does not get triggered if I change an attribute or an inline css style of an element. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the spec draft](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutationobserver), the property you want to set is `attributes: true`, not `attribute: true`.